# Page edit Issues

Tags: 2013, permissions, publishing-page, check-out

I am trying to edit a page in SharePoint 2013 and having issues.  I have all the proper permissions (I don't have site collection admin but full control).  I am able to edit the page, but only sometimes.  If someone checks the page out and back in I am not able to edit the page.  Actually it grey's the edit features out.  Then if I attempt the same thing hours or days later I may be able to edit.  I was able to edit the particular page before without issues, but not now I am not able to edit.  If I had site collection admin permissions it would work all the time, but I am not allowed to have that level.  But it shouldn't matter because I was able to edit the page with just full control permissions.  Has anyone experienced this issue before?

Comment: If someone else has the page checked out, you won't be able to make changes to it until they have checked it back in. Is that the problem here?

Comment: could you please tell me which browser you are using? if its IE 11, then try to put the site in compatibility view and try!

Comment: @EricAlexander Even if it's checked in the issue still exists

Comment: @SharePointer I am using the IE11 browser.  I will try to put the site in compatibility view. Thanks!